# Load an external JS library into a page using Greasemonkey

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey, javascript

I want a translator in my Firefox. I find some code from internet. but it doesn't run in my Firefox. I have installed Greasemonkey.

```
function loadBingTranslator() {
    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://dict.bing.com.cn/cloudwidget/Scripts/Generated/BingTranslate_Selection_ShowIcon.js';
    script.onload = initBingTranslator;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
};

function initBingTranslator() {
    BingCW.Init({
        MachineTranslation: true,
        WebDefinition: true
    });
}
loadBingTranslator();
```

Comment: `dict.bing.com.cn` -- are you sure you didn't just install a trojan?

Comment: *"I want a translator in my Firefox"* You mean like any of these addons: [one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gtranslate/) | [two](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-translator-for-firefox/) | [three](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/translator/)? (Just a sampling, there are more.)

Comment: It might be the way that Greasemonkey sandboxes the javascript.  Though I haven't had any problems inserting script tags previously...

Comment: Is there any errors that you can get from JavaScript Console or Firebug?

Comment: it shows nothing about the script from console.can it be written into a function that doest insert <script> tag?

Comment: hi Crowder, i want an addons that have a simple translating function that just show a board when i select or click some text.

Answer (score 1):

Such a script must account for the GM sandbox, and also (usually) allow time for the library to load and initialize.   See [Avoid Common Pitfalls (in Greasemonkey)](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Avoid_Common_Pitfalls).

So, you would use this library like so:

```
//--- Load the library.
var D           = document;
var appTarg     = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0]  ||  D.body  ||  D.documentElement;
var jsNode      = D.createElement ('script');

jsNode.src      = 'http://dict.bing.com.cn/cloudwidget/Scripts/Generated/BingTranslate_Selection_ShowIcon.js';
jsNode.addEventListener ("load", initBingTranslatorOnDelay, false);

appTarg.appendChild (jsNode);


//--- Allow some time for the library to initialize after loading.
function initBingTranslatorOnDelay () {
    setTimeout (initBingTranslator, 666);
}

//--- Call the library's start-up function, if any. Note needed use of unsafeWindow.
function initBingTranslator () {
    unsafeWindow.BingCW.Init ( {
        AppID:              "GM Foo",
        MachineTranslation: true,
        WebDefinition:      true
    } );
}
```

Issues, some specific to this question:

1. `onload` is not available; See the pitfalls.  Event handlers cannot be set this way in GM.  Also, `addEventListener()` is the best practice anyway.
2. Accessing JS (including libraries we load) in the page scope, requires `unsafeWindow`.
3. That app appears to want an `AppID`.
4. Sometimes, libraries like this can be loaded in the GM scope instead of the page scope, using the `// @require` directive.
   I did not try that with this library, but with others, it may be possible.   Do **not** try this with untrusted libraries, as they gain extra abilities to infect your machine, once inside the GM scope.
5. Don't use reserved words, like "script", for variable names.

Answer (score 0):

My JavaScript Console is outputting a "Component is not available"
line 10: script.onload = initBingTranslator;

So I fixed changed it to ... = initBingTranslator() because it is a function.

Now it says "BingCW is not definded"
Line 15: BingCW.Init({
        MachineTranslation: true,
        WebDefinition: true
    });

And it is right, not sure if something is missing or this is supposed to only work in IE, I would find a Google translator solution personally (or just use an existing add-on).

Answer (score 0):

Bing Dictionary hasd published a [Firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/zh-CN/firefox/addon/bing-dictionary-firefox-40-/?src=search).
You can use it directly.